# Vim autoindents 8 spaces for/if/case blocks when writing bash code

Tags: vim

Whenever I input a statement such as:

`if [[ x -eq $something ]]`

Or any "if", "for", or whatever statement, bash indents 8 spaces instead of 4 after I press enter.
So where I want my code to look like this:

```
for $i in {1..5}
    *do stuff*
    *do more stuff*
end
```

Vim autoindents it like this

```
for $i in {1..5}
        *do stuff*
        *more stuff*
end
```

How can I change vim's behavior?  It seems like bash scripts are the only thing that indent like this.

Comment: Can we see your full `vimrc`? Also, what is the current filetype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have these indent-related configurations in my .vimrc, can you test each one separately?

I'm very sure the last command with [autocmd](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html) will assist you with various indents for various languages.

```
filetype plugin indent on
filetype indent on

syntax enable
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
autocmd FileType javascript set tabstop=2|set shiftwidth=2|set expandtab
autocmd FileType sh set tabstop=4|set shiftwidth=4|set expandtab
```

Comment: Adding "set shiftwidth=4" is what fixed it.  Thanks!